# Request for links: Hadamard's Maximum Determinant Problem

Tags: complex-numbers, determinant, hadamard-matrices

Can I get some useful links or insight for reading up on Hadamard's Maximum Determinant Problem but with complex entries?

What this means is that the maximal determinant is the absolute of the complex determinant
That means there are entries: 1, -1, i, -i.